# Average amount of appearances of given set inside another set.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, average

So, I was studying a little bit, and I realised that the questions in my book(applied mechanics) which had an answer at the end of the book were of the form $[1,5,9,13,17,...]$, or $[2,6,10,...]$ or $[3,7,11,...]$ which is pretty obviously an arithmetical progression of the kind $a_n=j+4n$, with  $n$ starting at zero and $j=[1,2,3,4]$.

I wanted to know the **average** amount of exercises that will have an answer at the end of the book given a number n of exercises and given j is ANY of the options. I know it should be around $n/4$, because well, that is the inverse of the ratio of the arithmetic progression, but I wanted an answer with 100% precision. I am not very good at dealing with this kind of problem, that's why I am seeking help here.

Comment: It depends on the distribution from which the number of total exercises is drawn from.  For example, if every chapter/section has 3 questions and the ones at the end of the book start with 4, you will never have an answer at the end of the book.

Comment: Just to clarify a small detail, your formulation posits a zero-th exercise, which probably doesn't exist. If we also have the subset $\{4,8,12,\ldots\}$, try $n\ge 0$ and $j\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: @jed Hmmm...I don't see your point. I mean, we are talking about a real world problem here, ok? Let's say I did have $n=3$, numbered $1,2,3$ exercises at one chapter, then at the end of the book there would be, obviously, at least 1 answer for that chapter, and that would be $[a_0]=1$, or $[a_0]=2$, or $[a_0]=3$. Maybe the constraints in my question aren't well specified. Well, that's what I am here for, understanding and solving the problem.

Comment: @Brody yeah, you are right, I have to think that through better, realised that while writing the answer to Jed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you know is $n$ (the number of problems in the chapter), and you are flipping to the back of the book, you can expect there to be

$$A = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{j=1}^{4} \left(\left\lfloor\frac{n-j}{4}\right\rfloor+ 1\right) = \frac{1}{4}\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{4}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n-2}{4}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n-3}{4}\right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor + 3  \right) = \frac{n}{4}$$ answers, assuming random $j$ from $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, and where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

If the first term of an arithmetic progression is $j$ and the final term is $a_k = j + kd$ with common difference $d=4$, where the final term $a_k$ can't exceed $n$, we solve $j + kd \leq n$, or $k = \left\lfloor\frac{n-j}{d}\right\rfloor$. This tells us there are $\left\lfloor\frac{n-j}{4}\right\rfloor+1$ terms in the progression, counting $j$ itself.

As for the floor functions (call the sum of these $F$), one useful representation might be $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{y} \right\rfloor = \frac{x-(x \mod{y})}{y}$, which means:

$$F = \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{4}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n-2}{4}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n-3}{4}\right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor$$

$$F =\frac{4n-6-((n-1)\bmod{4}) -((n-2)\bmod{4}) -((n-3)\bmod{4}) -(n\bmod{4})}{4}$$

Note that no matter what $n$ is, the sum of the residues will always be $0 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 6$:

$$F =\frac{4n-6-6}{4} = n - 3$$

That gives us:

$$A = \frac{1}{4}((n-3)+3) = \frac{n}{4}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on why is that so?

Comment: So, I have tried several times to arive at your $n/4$ but i simply can't. Are you sure the answer isn't $n/4+3/8$? 

Apart from that, thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The average is equal to $n/4$ (no need for a $3/8$ term)

Comment: Why is that so?? You defined the average as your expression $A$, and that equals $n/4 + 3/8$, so I really don't get why $n/4$ would be the answer. I mean, once n tends to infinity, or even at big numbers, yeah, 3/8 is negligible, but lets say i only have 1 exercise in a chapter, then $n/4=0,25$ and $A=0,625$ which are pretty different answers for the amount of "answers" I will have on average on that chapter. If i could have partial answers, it would mean that in one case I get the start of the answer and the other i get almost a full answer. This could also be thought in terms of probability

Comment: Added some more detail. $A$ is definitely $n/4$. I'm not entirely sure where you're getting the $3/8$ piece from -- can you elaborate with what you're trying?

Comment: AAAH, nevermind, I hadn't realised that you had used the floor function, I was reading it as brackets. I assumed that in the step where you went from $j+kd≤n$ to the expression that determined $k$, you had just assumed the highest value o $k$ for a given $j$ and $n$, which is kind of silly now that i come to think about it. Thank you very much, now I get it. I wish I could +1 your answer twice.